# NumLock light ignores NumLock key on MSI laptop in 18.04

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, bug-reporting, msi, numlock

The numlock key works normally on my [MSI MS-1759 laptop](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GE70-2PE-Apache-Pro.html), but its indicator light does not. When the button is pressed, numlock toggles on but its light stays off. Via terminal it can be forced open with:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee '/sys/class/leds/input3::numlock/brightness'
```

When the NumLock key is pressed again, the light goes off again and cannot be turned on again. How can I sync the numlock button of my laptop's integrated keyboard to light?

Comment: @K7AAY It is just a laptop

Comment: @K7AAY MSI GE70 2PC, Model no: MS-1759

Comment: If you plug in another keyboard, can you change it by using the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fixed after lastest kernel update [4.15.0-24-generic].